# Excel freezes without use of Wait

Tags: excel, vba, wait

When I run my code, it freezes, however it will work when I insert `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))`, it works perfectly.  I am just wondering why it does that.  This is the first time something like this has happened.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
Public Sub Run()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Call Import

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Import()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim FileChosen As Integer
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim tempWB As Workbook

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    fd.InitialFileName = "X:\Dump Report for Loans"
    fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

    FileChosen = fd.Show
    If FileChosen = -1 Then
        Call Sort
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")) 'Heres where it trips
        Call Save_As
    Else:
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Sort()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim tempWB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim rwCnt As Long
    Dim rngSrt As Range
    Dim shRwCnt As Long

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count

        Set tempWB = Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(i))

        With tempWB.Worksheets(1)

            rwCnt = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Range("A1") <> "* as of *" Then
                If .Cells(rwCnt - 1, 1).NumberFormat = "mmm d, yyyy" Then
                    .Range("A1") = .Range("A1").Value & " as of " & .Cells(rwCnt - 1, 1)
                    .Rows(rwCnt - 1 & ":" & rwCnt).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
                    rwCnt = rwCnt - 2
                End If
            End If

            Set rngSrt = .Range("A2:AR" & rwCnt)

            With .Sort
                .SortFields.Clear
                .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E2:E" & rwCnt), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SetRange rngSrt
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With

            .Columns("F:F").Insert shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

            For x = rwCnt To 4 Step -1
                .Cells(x, 6).Value2 = (.Cells(x, 5).Value2 - .Cells(x - 1, 5).Value2)
            Next x

            For Z = rwCnt To 3 Step -1
                If .Cells(Z, 6).Value = 0 Then
                    .Rows(Z).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
                End If
            Next Z

            .Columns("F:F").Delete

            .Columns("A:AR").AutoFit

            Organize fd, tempWB, i, rwCnt
            Summary fd, tempWB, i

        End With
    Next i

    tempWB.Worksheets(2).Activate
    tempWB.Worksheets(1).Visible = xlSheetHidden      
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Organize(fd As FileDialog, tempWB As Workbook, i As Integer, rwCnt As Long)
    Dim rngSrt As Range
    Dim shRwCnt As Long

        With tempWB.Worksheets(1)

            rwCnt = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("A1") = .Range("A1").Value & " as of " & .Cells(rwCnt - 1, 1)
            .Rows(rwCnt - 1 & ":" & rwCnt).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
            rwCnt = rwCnt - 2

            Set rngSrt = .Range("A2:AR" & rwCnt)

            With .Sort
                .SortFields.Clear
                .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AR2:AR" & rwCnt), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E2:E" & rwCnt), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SetRange rngSrt
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With

            For x = rwCnt To 3 Step -1
                If .Cells(x, 5).Value = .Cells(x - 1, 5).Value Then
                    .Rows(x).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
                End If
            Next x

            rwCnt = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            For y = 3 To rwCnt
                Dim WsDest As Worksheet
                Set WsDest = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next 'try to find the worksheet
                Set WsDest = Worksheets(Left$(.Cells(y, 44).Value, 31)) 'worksheet names are limited to 31 characters
                On Error GoTo 0 're-activate error reporting

                If WsDest Is Nothing Then 'if ws does not exist
                    'add this sheet name it and copy/paste
                    Set WsDest = Worksheets.Add(, Worksheets(Sheets.Count))
                    WsDest.Name = Left$(.Cells(y, 44).Value, 31) 'worksheet names are limited to 31 characters

                    .Range("A1:AR2").Copy
                    WsDest.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, _
                        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    .Rows(y).Copy
                    WsDest.Cells(3, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, _
                        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    WsDest.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
                    WsDest.Columns("A:AR").AutoFit
                Else
                    'find last used row and copy/paste
                    shRwCnt = WsDest.Cells(WsDest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                    .Rows(y).Copy
                    WsDest.Cells(shRwCnt + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, _
                        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    WsDest.Columns("A:AR").AutoFit
                End If

            Next y

            .Columns("A:AR").AutoFit

        End With

    tempWB.Worksheets(1).Activate      
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Summary(fd As FileDialog, tempWB As Workbook, i As Integer)
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = tempWB
    Dim strName As String: strName = "Summary"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet, after:=wb.Worksheets(1))
    Dim rwCnt As Long
    Dim PCsht As Worksheet

    With ws
        .Name = strName

        For x = 3 To Sheets.Count
            Set PCsht = tempWB.Worksheets(x)
            rwCnt = PCsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(x, 1) = PCsht.Name
            .Cells(x, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(PCsht.Cells(3, 11), PCsht.Cells(rwCnt, 11)))
        Next x

        .Cells(2, 1) = "Purpose Code"
        .Cells(2, 2) = "Net Active Principle Balance"
        .Cells(Sheets.Count + 1, 1) = "TOTAL"
        .Cells(Sheets.Count + 1, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(ws.Cells(3, 2), ws.Cells(Sheets.Count, 2)))
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
        .Range(.Cells(3, 2), Cells(Sheets.Count + 1, 2)).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"

    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Save_As()
    Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean
    bFileSaveAs = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
    If Not bFileSaveAs Then MsgBox "User cancelled", vbCritical
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that Excel freezes? Does the macro actually stop executing? It sounds like the macro is just running normally, and adding a `wait` forces the macro to slow down and use less system resources. Excel 'freezing' doesn't necessarily mean anything bad is happening, it just means it's busy doing something. Whether or not that something is what you actually want it to do is another question.

Comment: @JoshEller It acts like it's in an infinite loop, so I have to close the application.  I understand that it works well, however, I would just like to not have to use a `wait`.

Comment: What is your code meant to do? Do you intend it to be an infinite loop?

Comment: No, I intend for it to run just as it does with the `wait`, but without needing the `wait`